# Cannot able to install postgres_copy module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot able to install postgres_copy module in my Mac. While i run my Python code i was getting the below error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'postgres_copy'
```

Then i tried to install the module by **pip3 install django-postgres-copy** and then i'm getting the below error. I have a custom script which uses this module , Can anyone please recommend or suggest something to resolve this error.

```
Collecting django-postgres-copy
  Using cached django_postgres_copy-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting psycopg2>=2.8.1
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-postgres-copy
  Attempting uninstall: psycopg2
    Found existing installation: psycopg2 2.7.6.1.dev1
    Uninstalling psycopg2-2.7.6.1.dev1:
      Successfully uninstalled psycopg2-2.7.6.1.dev1
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-install-n2f8u9iw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-install-n2f8u9iw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-record-0q5nj2id/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-install-n2f8u9iw/psycopg2/
    Complete output (151 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:138:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1717:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1822:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:82:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:30:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/aix_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/aix_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/aix_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:38:
    ./psycopg/config.h:82:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=130000 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of psycopg2
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.6.1.dev1.dist-info/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~sycopg2-2.7.6.1.dev1.dist-info
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-eo33vl7b/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libpq.5.10.dylib
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-eo33vl7b/libpq.5.10.dylib
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-eo33vl7b/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__init__.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/_ipaddress.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/_ipaddress.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/_json.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/_json.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/_range.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/_range.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/errorcodes.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/errorcodes.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/extensions.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/extensions.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/extras.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/extras.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/pool.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/pool.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/psycopg1.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/psycopg1.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/sql.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/sql.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__pycache__/tz.cpython-37.pyc
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/__pycache__/tz.cpython-37.pyc
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_ipaddress.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/_ipaddress.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/_json.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_range.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/_range.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/errorcodes.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/errorcodes.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/extensions.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/extras.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/pool.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/psycopg1.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/psycopg1.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/sql.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/sql.py
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/tests/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/~ests
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/tz.py
   from /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-uninstall-xx1tqvgd/tz.py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-install-n2f8u9iw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-install-n2f8u9iw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/t4/cb7x5vw1057cblh52hpnf0v00000gp/T/pip-record-0q5nj2id/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installation of `django-postgres-copy` package was unsuccessful because you don't have `pg_config` utility installed on your Mac. For simplicity, you can install postgresql via `brew` using this command (pg_config included in installation):

```
brew install postgresql
```

After that you can successfully install `django-postgres-copy` using this way:

```
pip3 install django-postgres-copy (if you have pip3 installed)
```

or

```
pip install django-postgres-copy
```